# Detect same words using different alphabets?

Tags: python

Python treats words `МАМА` and `MAMA` differently because one of them is written using latin and another using cyrillian.

How to make python treat them as one same string?

I only care about allomorphs.

Comment: search about `encoding` and `decoding` of strings in python

Comment: @jonrsharpe It's a question about characters that look similar but otherwise have nothing in common. It's not about "squeezing" a Unicode string into an ASCII representation.

Comment: @vpekar but that's *how* you convince it they're the same string, it won't believe you otherwise

Comment: @jonrsharpe the question is about transliteration. A Russian character can conventionally be transliterated into a Latin one, and you can't achieve this using unicodedata.normalize. See updated answer from Brendan Abel.

Comment: @vpekar OK, reopened, but did you actually read the first answer to the dupe I suggested? `unidecode` does all that

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, the first answer to that question is also a solution here.

Comment: Can you clarify if you only care about allomorphs, or does transliteration count? How would you want to deal with "PAPA", for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transliteration is not going to help (it will turn Cyrillic P into Latin R).  At first glance, Unicode compatibility form (NFKD or NFKC) look hopeful, but that turns U+041C (CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER EM) into U+041C (and not U+004D (LATIN CAPITAL LETTER EM)) - so that won't work.

The only solution is to build your own table of allomorphs, and translate all strings into a canonical form before comparing.

Note: When I said "Cyrillic P", I cheated and used the Latin allomorph - I don't have an easy way to enter Cyrillic.

Comment: OK. Thanks. I think it is the only way.

Answer (score 3):

There is a python library that will do the cyrillic to latin unicode translations called [`transliterate`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/transliterate/1.7.6)

```
>>> from transliterate import translit
>>> 
>>> cy = u'\u041c\u0410\u041c\u0410'
>>> en = u'MAMA'
>>> cy == en
False
>>> cy_converted = translit(cy, 'ru', reversed=True)
>>> cy_converted == en
True
>>> cy_converted
u'MAMA'
```

Comment: Wouldn't this make "ДРП" be considered equal to "DRP"? It kinda sounds like the OP only wants to consider allomorphs equal. This also seems like "РАРА" would transliterate to "RARA", which I suspect the OP doesn't want.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use normalize method.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize